# Dont shown UINavigationController on modalView

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm asking

```
[self presentModalViewController:searchRegionController animated:YES];
```

after that I try to add NavigationController by

```
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(next:)] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelAdd:)] autorelease]
    self.navigationItem.titleView =  someView;
```

Comment: please provide some more information on what you exactly  want ..do you want a navigation controller or navigation bar ? and in which method are you trying to add your navigationController ?

Comment: navigation bar. I just want custom navigation bar on modal view. If i'll go to view by "pushToView..." its working, but "presentModalView..." there isnt;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so do like this
in the searchRegionController class

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:naviBarObj];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem =[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(next:)] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelAdd:)] autorelease];

UINavigationItem *navigItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Navigation Title"];
navigItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
navigItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem;
naviBarObj.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: navigItem,nil];
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: that's because when you use PushToView you are actually pushing the view onto the NavigationController, so by default the NavigationController is visible, but when use presentModalView the view is not pushed onto the navigationController Stack,  its shown as an independent view, so the NavigationController from previous view is not shown. ..you get it.!!

Comment: oh, great. Dont have enought reputation to make + to u, but i really grateful to u :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)someAction
{
ViewController *object = [ViewController]alloc]initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle];

UINavigationController *navController = [UINavigationCOntroller]alloc]initWithRootViewController:object];

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

[object release];
[navController release];
}
```

And in the `viewDidLoad` of ViewController do :

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(next:)] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelAdd:)] autorelease]
    self.navigationItem.titleView =  someView;
```